# angular 2/4: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

Inside my logincomponent

```
    this.authenticationService.login('user', 'password').subscribe(comments => {
        alert('success');
    });
```

Inside my AuthService:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let url = 'http://22.5.66.58/api/v1/Identity/Login';
        console.log(this.data);
        return this.http.post(url, this.data, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your api route doesn't allow `POST` method, but maybe only `GET` or `PUT`. You have to fix on the API (server) side.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your backend side i am assuming that you your request didnt accept POST request.